# Ajax call to an external API to get a JSON - using JSONP

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

I need to perform an Ajax call to an external API to get a JSON formatted data, but I'm not getting any result.

I have this controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {

        $scope.list = MyService.fetchAll();
});
```

And this Service, to make an Ajax request to another domain:

```
var MyService = function($http) {
    this.fetchAll = function() {
        console.log('here1');

        $http.jsonp('http://other.domain.com/list/?allback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data) 
            console.log('here2');
            return angular.fromJson(data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('here3');
            console.log(status);
        });
    };
};

angular.module('myApp').service('MyService', MyService);
```

My Json returned is just:

[1,2,3,4,5]

When execute the code/request I didn't get the result excepted, the code in .success() never is executed. I get in console:

```
here1
here3
404
```

Any suggestion about how is the best approach to implement this will be appreciated. I'm newbie on this.

Comment: are you sure the json is coming back? your function appears to be throwing a 404 error meaning it isn't hitting the api at all

Comment: Yes, the request is made and I get the result [1,2,3,4,5]... (Checked in  network section, on DevTools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  console.log(status) printing 404 which means:

> The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code
>   indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given
>   server, but the server could not find what was requested.

double check url address.

you can make ajax call using factory that way:
(sample here http://jsfiddle.net/ty69u6tL/4/)

**FACTORY:**

```
app.factory('MyService', function ($http, $q) {

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // put your url here:////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var url = "http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/wtmpeachtest.wordpress.com/posts?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";


    this.fetchAll = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        console.log('here1');
        $http.jsonp(url).success(function (data) {
            console.log('here2');
            deferred.resolve(angular.fromJson(data));
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('here3');
            console.log(status);
            deferred.reject(data, status, headers, config);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    return this;
});
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
app.controller('jsonp_example', function ($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.doRequest = function () {
        MyService.fetchAll().then(onSucess, onError);

        function onSucess(response) {
            $scope.data = response;
        }

        function onError() {
            alert("Cant get data ");
        }        
    };
 });
```

**HTML***

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="jsonp_example">
        <button ng-click="doRequest()">Make JSONP request</button> <pre> {{data | json}}</pre>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I did it again... but I even get the request response code 200 (and json) in the DevTools network section. I know is weird that I get 404 and 200 in other side.

Comment: Please set the code in your answer (is remains here for others) to accept it. The main problem was that the requested API doesn't returns the callback reference, just return the JSON [1,2,3,4,5]. Instead is needed to return something like "JSON_CALLBACK([1,2,3,4,5])" With your code and the API change, all is working properly

Comment: @leticia it is done, good to hear to everything is working  :)

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that the external json request is an asynchronous operation, and that´s the root of your problem, when you call ´fetchAll()´ it will not wait for the request to complete and to return the values. To correct that you must return a promise from your service and assign your data on it´s ´then´ function.

```
var MyService = function($http, $q) {
    this.fetchAll = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();


        $http.jsonp('http://other.domain.com/list/?allback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){ 
            console.log('here2');
            deferred.resolve(angular.fromJson(data));
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('here3');
            deferred.reject(status);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
return this;
};
```

And at your controller, do this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
    MyService.fetchAll.then(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
    })
}, function(error){
    console.log(error);
    // Decide what to do with your $scope.list in case of an error
    $scope.list = null;
});
```

Comment: Thanks..+1 I updated the code, but now getting "TypeError: undefined is not a function" in this controller line "MyService.fetchAll.then("

Comment: I'd say that function fetchAll should return deferred.promise instead of $q.promise

Comment: @user3281440 you are absolutely right, that was my mistake, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

For archive purpose, I finally did it as follow (personally I think is the simplest approach):

In my service I have this:

```
this.fetchAll = function() {

        return $http.jsonp("<here API Endpoint>").then(function(response){
                return response.data;
        });
};
```

And in my controller:

```
MyService.fetchAll().then(function(data) {
    requestResult = data;
});
```

**Just a note**: The main problem was that the requested API doesn't returns the callback reference, just return the JSON [1,2,3,4,5]. Instead is needed to return something like "JSON_CALLBACK([1,2,3,4,5])"